Qt OpenGL ES 3.2 , QOpenGLShader::link: Link failed because of invalid fragment shader
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): 1:2: P0003: Warning: Extension 'GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions' not supported
4:2: S0022: Symbol 'texture' redeclared
4:7: L0001: Symbol 'texture' can't be referenced as a variable
*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
`#version 320 es 
#ifdef GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
#extension GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions : enable
#extension GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced : enable
#endif
#ifndef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
#define highp mediump
#endif
#line 1


precision mediump float;  
uniform sampler2D texture; 
in vec2 texc;  
out vec4 fragColor;  
void main(void) 
{ 
    fragColor = texture(texture, texc);  
}

 

QOpenGLShader::link: Link failed because of invalid fragment shader.
arm_release_ver of this libmali is 'g2p0-01eac0', rk_so_ver is '3'.Shader program linking failed: Link failed because of invalid fragment shader.
QOpenGLShader::link: Link failed because of invalid fragment shader.
Shader program linking failed: Link failed because of invalid fragment shader.
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(texture): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLTexture::setFormat(): Cannot change format once storage has been allocated
Cannot resize a texture that already has storage allocated.
To do so, destroy() the texture and then create() and setSize()
Cannot set mip levels on a texture that already has storage allocated.
To do so, destroy() the texture and then create() and setMipLevels()
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(texture): shader program is not linked


the task is very simple,show a picure.


"Symbol 'texture' redeclared 4:7: L0001: Symbol 'texture' can't be referenced as a variable": the error message seems pretty clear -- name your sampler2D uniform something other than texture.

Note that the remaining text in your post suggests you have multiple other issues in your code besides the linker error but it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you with those unless you provide a [mcve].

To add to what G.M. said: texture is the name of a builtin function, so it cannot be used as a variable name. It would be similar to trying to name a variable while or for.
